# SO like URL with mod_rewrite

Tags: url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to get a URL scheme exact like SO's question URL.

Like `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6035363/so-like-url-with-mod-rewrite`

this page can be accessed with `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6035363`
but then it redirects to the `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6035363/so-like-url-with-mod-rewrite`

I need to do the same.
My page will be in the root directory named article.php
the url will be like

```
article.php?id=1&title=some_text
```

i want it to be accessed with [any of these will do]

```
acticle.php/id/1/some_text
```

or

```
acticle/id/1/some_text
```

or

```
acticle/id/1&title=some_text
```

**[Sorry i really dont know about mod_rewrite so i read some question and googled some cheat sheets but none of them worked :(

So looking for some copy-paste solution]**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's best if you divide and conquer the URL to reverse engineer it.

So a few key points:

1. `6035363` is the important part of the URL as it's the question ID.
2. Everything else is arbitrary SEO, friendly URLs
3. Having multiple URLs of the same page will hurt SEO, so stick to one URL format

With that said, `article/id/some_keyword_text` is the format I suggest. The following RewriteRules will handle it.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^article/(\d+)/?$ test/article.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^article/(\d+)/([\w-]+)/?$ test/article.php?id=$1&title=$2 [L]
```

The first rule redirects `article/id` with an optional trailing slash. The second rule redirects `article/id/some_keyword_text` with an optional trailing slash. `some_keyword_text` may only contain alphanumeric, underscore, or dash characters.

**Note:** The redirection for URLs of format `article/id` happens at the page level. So this is not a RewriteRule, but logic in the page that redirects when `title` is not set. I'm guessing a 301 Redirect to ensure point #3.

Comment: it redirects to root/article.php :(

Comment: I don't know what that means. Please elaborate.

Comment: i have put article.php as root/test/article.php, when i try to browse it it redirects to root/article.php

Comment: So `article.php` lives in the `test` directory under webroot (`root`)?

Comment: I've modified my answer to redirect to `test/article.php`.

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6035633/hide-or-change-page-extension-with-mod-rewrite/6035684#6035684

Comment: Glad it worked. As a side note, more information is better on SO. That is to say Questions and Comments don't have to be as short as possible.

Comment: Can you help me a little bit more ! Your _RewriteRule_ works perfectly but when i browse `http://localhost/test/article/` it shows page not found ! is there any way to redirect it to `http://localhost/test/article.php` or continue working as the user have requested to browse `http://localhost/test/article.php`  with _RewriteRule_ ?

Comment: You can add the following as your first rule: `RewriteRule ^article/?$ test/article.php [L]`

Comment: can you have a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6035633/hide-or-change-page-extension-with-mod-rewrite