# Hide or Change page extension with mod_rewrite

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

how can i change all my php page to show as html page in the browser ?
What will be the file name when they will save a x.php file ?

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the following in a .htaccess file at the main directory of your site (public_html or www), or httpd.conf (or similar) if you aren't on shared hosting and have root access to the server:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php
```

When someone tries to save the page, it will save as .html (they will never know it was really a .php file!)

Comment: it redirects to root/file.html :(

Comment: Where did you define the rule? root/.htaccess?

Comment: i placed the .htaccess file in root/test and the test.php page is in root/test/test.php, now when i try to browse root/test/test.php it redirects to root/test.php

Comment: It should work if you move it into root/.htaccess, otherwise I think you'll need to include a `RewriteBase /test` ([docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase))